# Why do promises execute at the point of declaration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I would like to execute a set of promises using Promise.all(). My approach is to put these promises in an array and then pass the array to Promise.all().  However, I find that the promises start executing as soon as they are declared and do not even wait for Promise.all to be called.

Why is this happening and how can I have the promises only execute upon calling Promise.all()?

```js
let promiseArray = [];
const values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

values.forEach((value)=>{
  promiseArray.push(
    new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      console.log('value: ' + value);
      return resolve();
    })
  )
})


console.log('start')
Promise.all(promiseArray)

/*
 output is 

  value: 1
  value: 2
  value: 3
  value: 4
  value: 5
  start

 would have expected output to have been

  start
  value: 1
  value: 2
  value: 3
  value: 4
  value: 5
*/
```

Comment: that is how they are designed to work - the Promise executor is executed immediately and synchronously ... there is no simple answer as to why.

Comment: if you want the code to behave as you expect, simple change to one line ... `promiseArray.push(() =>` and then `Promise.all(promiseArray.map(fn => fn()))`

Comment: Your intuition is actually reasonable. The design decision to eagerly execute the Promises constructor is at least questionable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thinking of promises as "executing" is getting you confused.  A promise is purely a notification mechanism.  It is typically tied to some underlying asynchronous operation and when you create the promise, the asynchronous operation is typically started.

`Promise.all()` is then used to track when a whole bunch of asynchronous operations that **you've already started** have completed (or ended with an error).

So, you don't use `Promise.all()` to start a bunch of things.  You use it just to track when they are all done and they are started elsewhere in your code.

---

When you manually create a promise with `new Promise()`, the promise executor is executed immediately.  That's how they are designed.

If you had real asynchronous operations in your promise executor and you were doing `console.log()` when those operations completed, you'd probably not find any issue with how promises are designed.  I think most of your confusion stems from the fact that you don't actually have any asynchronous operation inside your promise executor and thus there's really no reason to even use a promise for that.  Promises are designed to track the completion of asynchronous operations.  No reason to use them if you don't have an actual asynchronous operation.

FYI, if you want to start some asynchronous operation at some time in the future from inside the promise executor, you can use the normal `setTimeout()` or `process.nextTick()` or `setImmediate()` operations to schedule the operation to start later.

> would have expected output to have been

Plus, it appears you are expecting your output to be in a strict order.  `Promise.all()` expects there to be N asynchronous operations running in parallel and there is no guaranteed order of completion for those N operations.  Instead, `Promise.all()` will track them all, collect all the results and present the `.then()` handler with an array of results in order (if they all resolved successfully).  It does not run the operations themselves in order.  The operations run in parallel and complete in whatever natural order they take.

Comment: This just blew my mind!  My mental model for promises has always been that they were "special" functions that "resolved" as opposed to "returned" hence making them appropriate for asynchronous operations.  Now I just need to go figure out why my current code works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @takinola - It's not an uncommon confusion.  But, if you have a function that returns a promise, think of it like this.  The function starts an asynchronous operation, then creates a new promise and hooks it up to monitor that asynchronous operation.  The function then returns that promise that's like a tracker you can use to know when the async operation is done and what result it finished with.  The promise is not the operation itself, just a tracking mechanism.  One would typically have a single function to both start an async operation and get a promise back to track it.

Comment: I finally can say I'm not *completely* clueless about promises !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, promises execute right away. They couldn't work any other way. Promises, just like any other object in JS, are completely unaware of what is referencing them and how they get passed around, so there's no way for them to "wait" until something particular is getting done with the references to them.

The solution in your case is to create the promises as you pass them to `Promise.all()`:

```
let promiseFnArray = [];
const values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

values.forEach((value) => {
  promiseFnArray.push((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('value: ' + value);
    return resolve();
  }))
})

console.log('start')
Promise.all(promiseFnArray.map(promiseFn => new Promise(promiseFn));
```

Also, once your promises actually make something asynchronous, they won't necessarily resolve in the original order. To get the results in the correct order you use `Promise.all( ... ).then()`, which is the entire purpose of `Promise.all()`

Comment: `[...]They couldn't work any other way. [...]` that's not true a `new Promise` could delay the execution of the callback that is passed to the constructor using `setImmediate` and then the `start` would appear before the `value: ` outputs. But this does not make much sens, because Promises are normally used to observer async code (see the answer of [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685827/1960455))

Comment: @t.niese AFAIK, `setImmediate` is not standard and it would not delay the Promise's invokation of the executor, it just means you wrap your code in a separate delay. That has nothing to do with the promise itself or how it gets passed around. _"couldn't work any other way"_ was in reference to the notion that the promise would be able to invoke the executor depending on what happens to a variable that references it (in this case being passed to `Promise.all()`)

Comment: Yes `setImmediate`/`setTimeout` ... are not part of the language specification, I just used it as illustration. The OP is wondering why `start`  is displayed after `value`. The assumption often arises, because Promises are use for async code, and in nodejs all callbacks that might be called async should always be called async (all those `err, value` callbacks). So some people expect that the callback passed to `new Promise` will also be called async like those `err, value` callbacks. And the Promise implementation could for sure do that, but it does not make sense.