# Does an un awaited promise get executed if the Lambda has already returned response

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, performance, aws-lambda

Lets say I have a Node JS lambda, that goes like:

```
const _helper= async(){
  var dbResponse1= await getDataFromDB(); // 150 ms
  computation(dbResponse1);
  var dbResponse2= await dbTransaction(); // 3 separate db calls, 500 ms
  if (someCondition){
    await pushToNotificationQueue(); // 100 ms
  }
}

const handler= async(event, context)=> {
  var getData= await getDataFromDB();
  _helper();
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    message: "",
    body: getData
  }
}
```

Will the promise returned by _helper be fulfilled or the return statement of hander is the end for _handler as well?

Comment: You need to await `_helper` otherwise lambda will just cancel it after `handler` is done

Comment: [Promises are not "getting executed"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685827/1048572)

Comment: It depends. Sometimes the requests you've started will finish, sometimes they will not - AWS will kill the process after you've returned a response or it might call `handler` again for the next event. Do not rely on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to `await` your `_helper` function. Your lambda is terminated as soon as `handler` is done.

So back to your question:

> ...handler is the end for _handler as well

Yes