# Execute promises after each other or apply timeouts to promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have a function in React app where will be made three different http calls:

```js
const handleEditUser = async () => {
  let p1, p2, p3;

  p1 = UserUtils.setProjects(user, client, newProjects);

  p2 = UserUtils.updateRights(user.id, userAuthority);

  p3 = UserUtils.updateUserClient(client, user);

  await Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]);
}
```

My problem is that `p2` request will be executed before `p1` request was completely finished.

I would like to build some timeouts or something else which allows to execute `p2` after `p1` is finished and `p3` after `p2` is finished.

I tried to replace `Promise.all[]` with the lines below, but it didn't solve my problem:

```js
await p1;
await p2;
await p3;
```

Comment: [Promises are not "executed"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685827/1048572). When you call your three methods, you've started three asynchronous processes, `await`ing them afterwards won't change anything. You'll need to `await` the first before even *calling* the second method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening:

```js
const handleEditUser = async () => {
  let p1, p2, p3

  p1 = UserUtils.setProjects(user, client, newProjects) // request p1 starting

  p2 = UserUtils.updateRights(user.id, userAuthority) // request p2 starting

  p3 = UserUtils.updateUserClient(client, user) // request p3 starting

  await Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]) // waiting for all of those to finish
                                  // but requests are already fired

  // or

  await p1 // waiting for p1 to finish, p2 and p3 are running in parallel
  await p2 // waiting for p2 to finish, p3 can still be running in parallel
  await p3
}
```

Basically, when your `UserUtils` methods are actually starting the workflow of the promises. So you should rather consider wait for one promise to be over before starting the next workflow:

```
const handleEditUser = async () => {
  await UserUtils.setProjects(user, client, newProjects)

  await UserUtils.updateRights(user.id, userAuthority)

  await UserUtils.updateUserClient(client, user)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for Promise.all[]

Your requirement is to execute promises one after another, then async with await will work here.

You can try this way.

```
const handleEditUser = async () => {
  let p1, p2, p3;

  p1 = await UserUtils.setProjects(user, client, newProjects);

  p2 = await UserUtils.updateRights(user.id, userAuthority);

  p3 = await UserUtils.updateUserClient(client, user);
}
```

Note: UserUtils methods should be a promise

Comment: Minor correction: `UserUtils` methods do not need to return promises. If what is being awaited does not return a Promise, then await wraps it in a promise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262996/does-awaiting-a-non-promise-have-any-detectable-effect

Comment: @Terry "should" != "must". There's no point in ever awaiting something that's not a promise (or promise-like), so Jeevan is correct, it _should_ be a promise.